# Link turns white when clicked even though a:active has been set to purple

Tags: css

On my site, most links (apart from those in the navbar) turn white when clicked or right-clicked. E.g. http://wisderm.com/ingredients/Dead+Sea

This is despite my setting links to #6f5499, which is a purple colour: http://www.color-hex.com/color/6f5499, as such:

```
a, a:hover, a:focus, a:active { color: #6f5499; }
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the CSS code below. The rule after the comma(`,`) targets every link of the webpage instead of the links inside `alert`

```
.alert a:hover, a:focus { color: white; }
```

Change it to

```
.alert a:hover, .alert a:focus { color: white; }
```